# Creating an odd function $f(x)$ such that $g(x) = f(x - 18)$ is an even function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, even-and-odd-functions

I am tasked with finding an example of a function $f(x)$ such that the function $g(x) = f(x-18)$ is an even function.

I understand even and odd functions. However, I am unsure how to create an odd function such that shifting it will make it even.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about sine and cosine. They are just translations of each other.

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(x+18)^2$. Then, $g(x)=f(x-18)=x^2$, which is clearly an even function.

In general, $f(x)=(x+18)^n \ \forall $ even $n$ works too.

Comment: of course there are several other possibilites; this is merely one specific example.